# Is a glass shower screen a suitable backing for mosaics?

Tags: shower, glass, mosaic

I have an old boxed-in corner shower. The glass screen has three panels which are all very hazy. I can't afford to replace it right now. I was thinking of putting mosaics (big pictures - not little squares) on a couple of the panels to distract from how bad the shower looks. There is one panel in particular that measures 21 cm wide and 159 cm long. I will put the mosaic on the outside (away from the water).

Is the shower screen glass itself a suitable backing and if so, does it need to be prepared in some way? I plan to use glass for the tiles (cut to shape for the picture) and clear adhesive. Not sure though if it will stick and if just adhering direct to the shower screen will be ok. Also, what can I use as grout between the glass pieces? I have only ever done glass mosaics on pottery with coloured grout. Do I need to grout? I would need to use something clear - can I use clear silicon? Thanks.

Comment: Are you opposed to simply trying to remove the "haze" from the glass screen?  It could be as simple as hard water buildup or soap scum that is creating the haze or as difficult as microscratching from repeated scrubbings or caustic cleaning chemicals.  If you're willing to try to restore the glass, I would start with a CLR/water solution, spray it on, leave for a few minutes, then spray it again before scrubbing it down.  If that doesn't remove the haze, then it's likely microscratches that could be polished off with polishing compound.

Comment: Hi Tim. I have tried all the options for clearing the haze and it seems to be inside the glass rather than soap scum or build up from hard water (we have very hard water here). The shower is pretty old (1980s) so I think its beyond fixing. I just don't want to replace it until I renovate the whole bathroom as I want to reorganise where everything is.

Comment: I would consider the total weight of all glass you plan to add, and the strength of the shower door hinge. If you estimate the glass to add weight much more than the existing door, this might be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Generally glass bonding is done with a special adhesive that is UV cured.  I'm uncertain as much as far as the cost for it.  I have always used silicone to bond glass, it's what my family business uses to assemble/repair fish tanks.

The silicone would also work perfect for you in place of grout.